# ModuleNotFoundError: 'script-name.py' when calling a script from another

Tags: python, numpy, module

I have two scripts where the main imports the other. When I don't have the file `"_pycache_"`, the main script runs normally (and creates this file), but if I relaunch the interpreter (Spyder) and run the program, there's an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SS2'`. I don't know why, but when I delete `_pycache_` and run the main script again, then there's no error.

Is really `_pycache_` the source of the problem?
How can I fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
import SS2 
import numpy as np

N=2 
L=2. 
frames=10

B=np.zeros((N,2))
B[:,0]+=np.linspace(-L,L,N,endpoint=True)
S=np.zeros((N,2)) 
R=0.01*np.random.randint(-1,2,size=(N,2)) 


SS2.states(B,S,R,L,N,frames)
```

PD: SS2 just uses the given input to create a DataFrame (using pandas) and then save it in a xlsx file.

Comment: do you have this problem when you run it without `Spyder`?

Comment: I haven't try it, because Spyder is the only IDE I have.

Comment: try without any `IDE` - normally in console/terminal/cmd.exe - `python script.py`

Comment: I tried it in anaconda prompt and it worked, but I don't think this is a solution, because I wouldn't be able to use Spyder then.

Comment: it only may confirm that problem can be `Spyder`. You can reinstall it. And if it will not help then you can go to Spyder's authors and search more info - maybe someone already had this problem. Or you can send isssue with information that it works without Spyder.

Comment: I just realized that it works normally when it is not running in a cell. I'll try reinstalling it. Otherwise, I'll send an issue to Spyder's support. Thank you!